# How to check/verify whether I have integrated SQLCipher corretly into my Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have integrated **SQLCipher** for a simple application for testing purpose. I have integrated it through cocoa pods.I am using **SQLite Manager** to view my **Model.sqlite** file. But I dont find any encrypted data out there. I can easily read the data which are inserted. 
And I have followed steps given out [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/).

I have added below code in appdelegate as given in the above link and when I run the application and it going inside if statement.
// Set up a SQLCipher database connection:

```
sqlite3 *db;
if (sqlite3_open([[self.databaseURL path] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char* key = [@"StrongPassword" UTF8String];
    sqlite3_key(db, key, (int)strlen(key));
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Password is correct, or a new database has been initialized");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Incorrect password!");
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is much anyone can do to help until you show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are not linking to `libsqlite3.dylib`.  Finally, you can verify the database itself is encrypted by running `hexdump -C yourDatabaseFile.db` and confirm that you do not see any plain text representing either the schema or data of the database.

Comment: I have deleted libsqlite3.dylib from link Binary with Libraries but still when run hexdump -C mydatabasefile.sqlite I can see unencrypted data. For me .db file is not getting generated.

Comment: You will need to apply a schema and insert data to verify the database in encrypted.  Your code above only opens a connection to a database file, then keys it.  You still need data.

Comment: I have schema in place and I am inserting and fetching data. When I use **hexdump -C myDatabase.sqllite** I can see all the data which were inserted into myDatabase.